# Windows 7 64bit + JDK/JRE = Slow System

Tags: windows, java, jdk

Each time I install JDK/JRE I feel that my system has a bit more overhead to it and it feels a bit "heavier" than before. Are there any services that startup with JDK or Java related that get installed to my system and if they do, is there a way to disable them?

Thanks!

Comment: This question makes no sense.  The services that are installed are only ran when they are needed.  My guess the "heavier" feel, whatever that means, it just a imaginary loss in performance.

Answer (score 1):

One resident process that is installed alongside the JRE is the [Java Updater](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml).

The linked page also shows  how to disable it:

> ### III. Configure Java Updates
>
> #### Automatic Update Feature
>
> 1. Click **Start > Settings > Control Panel** (For Windows XP)
>      Click **Start > Control Panel** (For Windows Vista and Windows 7)
> 2. Double-click **Java** icon. The Java Control Panel appears.
> 3. Click the **Update** tab
>      **Note:**
>
>    - The **Update** tab may not be available if your network administrator has disabled the Java Update feature during installation.
>    - If you are not logged in to system as administrator then options to change Java update notifications will be greyed out and user will not be able to change it.
> 4. To enable Java Update to automatically check for updates, select the **Check for Updates Automatically** check box.
> 5. To disable Java Update, un-select the **Check for Updates Automatically** check box.

Obviously, it will also install ActiveX components and such, which **might** have a minor impact on overall system performance. But I don't think they should be noticeable. And if you wanted to get rid of **those**, then I don't think the JRE will still work.

Comment: I always have issues on Windows Machines used for developing java applications. I think I'll just use Linux for my Java apps cause I simply don't trust the way MS WIndows work..